# string manipulation copying portions of a string c programming

Tags: c, arrays, string, copy, buffer

If I have a `char buffer[256]` in C that is populated, and I want to copy all characters from `buffer[5]` to `buffer[25]` into `char derp[20]` and have derp be null-terminated, how should I do it?
Edit (1): math `char derp[21]`
Edit (2): math! `char derp[22]`
To clarify some things, here is some of my code and the problems I've encountered with it:

```
char buffer[256];
char derp[20];
...
strncpy(derp, &buffer[5], 20); //copy into derp
printf("buffer:  %s\n", buffer); //print what I had
printf("derp:  %s\n", derp); //print what I got
```

`buffer` will hold some string like "OPEN account".
What I'm attempting to do is copy "account" from `buffer` into `derp` without copying "OPEN ".
The output will return:

```
buffer:  OPEN  
derp:
```

If I change `buffer` to hold "OPENaccount" without the space, the output will return:

```
buffer:  OPEN  
derp:  account
```

I understand that `strncpy` might look at whitespaces differently, but then why don't my first set of results return anything?  I also tried changing `&buffer[5]` to `&buffer[6]` but received the same result.

Comment: `derp` needs 22 elements.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, okay, thank you.  Assuming I initialize it to `char derp[21]` instead, how do I make the copy from `buffer` to `derp`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I suggest that you should fix the sample sizes in your question so that it can be answered; elements 5 through 25 of the buffer occupy 21 bytes, and then you need a null terminator too.  When you've fixed that, you can please explain to us what the problem you're having is?  There are a multitude of ways to do it — which one(s) have you tried?  What was the problem you had with the one(s) you tried?  We'll help you sort out your attempts; we don't usually go and write the code for you.

Comment: `char derp[22]; memcpy(derp, &buffer[5], 21); derp[21]=0;`

Comment: Note that `strncpy()` does not null terminate the target string when the source string is longer than space in the target string.

Comment: `buffer:  OPEN ` :  probably `buffer[5]` is `'\0'`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,  I think your correct, for the problem that the OP is seeing, however, the OP stated that that position in the buffer is a space, not a NUL byte

Comment: @user3629249 Perhaps there is a problem with the configuration of the string to the buffer. E.g `scanf("%s", buffer)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,  to determine what is actually in the `buffer[]` array would require posting the code that fills that array.  I did make the assumption, in my answer, that the OP knows what is actually in the buffer

Answer (score 0):

Use `strncpy`.

```
char *p = &buffer[5];
char derp[22];
strncpy(derp, p, 21); // Copy 21 characters from buffer[5] to buffer[25]
derp[21] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

//buffer[5] to buffer[25] into char derp[20]

Well, remembering that the character count to be copied is actually 21 characters and still need room for the NUL terminator character...

```
char buffer[30];  // 30 is arbitrary, must be greater than 26
char derp[22];

int j = 0;
for( int i = 5; i < 25; i++, j++ )
{
    derp[j] = buffer[i];
}
derp[i] = '\0';
```

or better:

```
char buffer[30]; // 30 is arbitrary, must be greater than 26
char derp[22] = {'\0'};

int j = 0;
for( int i = 5; i < 25; i++, j++ )
{
    derp[j] = buffer[i];
}
```

Comment: when downvoting, how about a comment as to why the downvote.

Comment: this answer does properly answer the question by the OP on how to copy a segment of the buffer.   If the buffer does not contain a valid char string or contains more than one valid char string is not material to how to copy a sub set of the characters in the buffer[] array

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that `strncpy` might look at whitespaces differently…

`strncpy` may in no case look at whitespaces differently. In all likelihood BLUEPIXY is right, who wrote:

> `buffer:  OPEN`  :  probably `buffer[5]` is
>   `'\0'`.